# How to use a memory mapped file from Python and pass it to an external API that requires a filename?

Tags: python, mmap

I have to call, from Python 2.5, an external API (win32) that request me to provide a filename and return a result.

In order to speedup the process I don't want to save the data into a classic file and I would prefer to save it in memory and release it after the API call returns.

The external function does need only read access.

I looked at [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) but the examples were not quite extensive ;)

Comment: Using a classic file should be fine.  The operating system shouldn't actually write the data to disk, but rather buffer it in memory.  `mmap` won't help here -- it is for mapping real files on the disk into virtual memory.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure that the OS doesn't do a proper job here!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a named pipe ?

on Windows, a named pipe can be accessed using standard file functions (`CreateFile()`, `ReadFile()`, `WriteFile()`...), using a special filename of the form `\\.\pipe\name`. your external API may be able to read from the pipe, a pipe that you would create from your python script and feed with the necessary data.